# GCP custom policy, restrict resources

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I want to restrict GCP resources via a custom policy.
1- specific VM types,
2- Storage size restrictions only 10GB allowed size selection.

Is this possible in GCP that we restrict users to create specific types of resources?

I have created a custom role, that only allowed create, update, delete and list operations on GCP resources.

I cannot restrict user that specific type of VM Instance creation allowed.

Comment: review this public documentation [Restricting resource usage](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/restricting-resources)

Comment: Do you use custom organisation policy?

Comment: Restrict resource usage, only restrict service not service-specific type e.g instance type or Storage size restriction.

Comment: upon further checking, this feature is not yet available. you can follow 
and update to this tracker https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/261603660